# RabbitListener does not pick up every message sent with AsyncRabbitTemplate

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous, integration-testing, spring-rabbit

I am using a Spring-Boot project on Spring-Boot Version 1.5.4, with `spring-boot-starter-amqp`, `spring-boot-starter-web-services` and `spring-ws-support` v. 2.4.0.
So far, I have successfully created a `@RabbitListener` Component, which does exactly what it is supposed to do, when a message is sent to the broker via `rabbitTemplate.sendAndReceive(uri, message)`. I tried to see what would happen if I used `AsyncRabbitTemplate` for this, as it is possible that the message processing might take a while, and I don't want to lock my application while waiting for a response.

The problem is: the first message I put in the queue is not even being picked up by the listener. The callback just acknowledges a success with the published message instead of the returned message.

**Listener:**

```java
@RabbitListener(queues = KEY_MESSAGING_QUEUE)
public Message processMessage(@Payload byte[] payload, @Headers Map<String, Object> headers) {
    try {
        byte[] resultBody = messageProcessor.processMessage(payload, headers);
        MessageBuilder builder = MessageBuilder.withBody(resultBody);
        if (resultBody.length == 0) {
            builder.setHeader(HEADER_NAME_ERROR_MESSAGE, "Error occurred during processing.");
        }
        return builder.build();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return MessageBuilder.withBody(EMPTY_BODY)
                .setHeader(HEADER_NAME_ERROR_MESSAGE, ex.getMessage())
                .setHeader(HEADER_NAME_STACK_TRACE, ex.getStackTrace())
                .build();
    }
}
```

When I am executing my Tests, one test fails, and the second test succeeds. The class is annotated with `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)` and `@SpringBootTest(classes = { Application.class, Test.TestConfiguration.class })` and has a `@ClassRule` of `BrokerRunning.isRunningWintEmptyQueues(QUEUE_NAME)`

**TestConfiguration (inner class):**

```java
public static class TestConfiguration {

    @Bean // referenced in the tests as art
    public AsyncRabbitTemplate asyncRabbitTemplate(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate) {
        SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer(connectionFactory);
        container.setQueueNames(QUEUE_NAME);
        return new AsyncRabbitTemplate(rabbitTemplate, container);
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageListener messageListener() {
        return new MessageListener();
    }
}
```

**Tests:**

```java
@Test
public void shouldListenAndReplyToQueue() throws Exception {
    doReturn(RESULT_BODY)
            .when(innerMock)
            .processMessage(any(byte[].class), anyMapOf(String.class, Object.class));
    Message msg = MessageBuilder
            .withBody(MESSAGE_BODY)
            .setHeader("header", "value")
            .setHeader("auth", "entication")
            .build();

    RabbitMessageFuture pendingReply = art.sendAndReceive(QUEUE_NAME, msg);
    pendingReply.addCallback(new ListenableFutureCallback<Message>() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Message result) { }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    });

    while (!pendingReply.isDone()) {}
    result = pendingReply.get();
    // assertions omitted
}
```

**Test 2:**

```java
@Test
public void shouldReturnExceptionToCaller() throws Exception {
    doThrow(new SSLSenderInstantiationException("I am a message", new Exception()))
            .when(innerMock)
            .processMessage(any(byte[].class), anyMapOf(String.class, Object.class));
    Message msg = MessageBuilder
            .withBody(MESSAGE_BODY)
            .setHeader("header", "value")
            .setHeader("auth", "entication")
            .build();

    RabbitMessageFuture pendingReply = art.sendAndReceive(QUEUE_NAME, msg);
    pendingReply.addCallback(/*same as above*/);

    while (!pendingReply.isDone()) {}
    result = pendingReply.get();
    //assertions omitted
}
```

When I run both tests together, the test that is executed first fails, while the second call succeeds.
When I run both tests separately, both fail.
When I add an `@Before`-Method, which uses the AsyncRabbitTemplate `art` to put any message into the queue, both tests MAY pass, or the second test MAY not pass, so in addition to being unexpected, the behaviour is inconsistent as well.

The interesting thing is, that the callback passed to the method reports a success before the listener is invoked, and reports the sent message as result.

The only class missing from this is the general configuration class, which  is annotated with `@EnableRabbit` and has this content:

```java
@Bean
public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory simpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    factory.setConcurrentConsumers(10);
    return factory;
}
```

Other Things I have tried:

- specifically create `AsyncRabbitTemplate` myself, start and stop it manually before and after every message process -> both tests succeeded
- increase / decrease receive timeout -> no effect
- remove and change the callback -> no effect
- explicitly created the queue again with an injected `RabbitAdmin` -> no effect
- extracted the callback to a constant -> tests didn't even start correctly
- As stated above, I used `RabbitTemplate` directly, which worked exactly as intended

If anyone has any ideas what is missing, I'd be very happy to hear.

Comment: It sounds like the message is being sent before the queue is bound to the exchange (which would be odd). Have you turned on DEBUG logging to examine the queue declaration and to and followed the message flow?

Comment: I did in fact turn on debug logging, as far as I can read this, the message gets created, published to the queue and simply does not return. The second message acts as expected. What I did find during debugging, however, is that there seem to be two `MessageListenerContainers` registered. One is the `AsyncRabbitTemplate` and the other is a `MessageListenerContainer`, and only the second actually contains the `RabbitListener`. So this looks like a configuration issue. Can there be a conflict with the `SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the same queue for requests and replies...

```
@Bean // referenced in the tests as art
public AsyncRabbitTemplate asyncRabbitTemplate(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate) {
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer(connectionFactory);
    container.setQueueNames(QUEUE_NAME);
    return new AsyncRabbitTemplate(rabbitTemplate, container);
}
```

Will listen for replies on QUEUE_NAME, so...

```
RabbitMessageFuture pendingReply = art.sendAndReceive(QUEUE_NAME, msg);
```

...simply sends a message to itself. It looks like you intended...

```
RabbitMessageFuture pendingReply = art.sendAndReceive(KEY_MESSAGING_QUEUE, msg);
```

Comment: KEY_MESSAGING_QUEUE is just a SPELExpression for QUEUE_NAME, as this whole thing MIGHT be used for multiple channels in the future.
So you're saying I need 2 channels for sendAndReply - I will try this out later, but I wonder why the second message works as intended.
Please note that the first request was sent (according to the logs) to a url ending on `,1`, while the second was sent to a url ending with `,2` - is that normal or does that hint at something going wrong?

Comment: Yes, you need two queues (not sure what you mean by "channel"). It works intermittently because you have two containers competing for messages; sometimes the template's container gets the message, sometimes the real container gets it.